# Dojo >= 1.7 build - remove files merged/inlined by process.

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

The Dojo build does 2 basic things:

- it merges JS modules into layer files and flatteden NLS files
- it inlines CSS imports

But everything is copied to the release folder.

As difference to the question [Dojo 1.7 custom build - How to remove unused files from the release folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682699/dojo-1-7-custom-build-how-to-remove-unused-files-from-the-release-folder), I want to keep modules that are 'unused' by build - the modules that are not merged into layers would be impossible to use if deleted.

But I want to **delete** every resource that was **merged/flattened/inlined**.

Is it possible to configure Dojo build to remove processed resources, or plug in into the build process to do that? Doing that in custom script isn't so hard for CSS, but for JS module I'd need to analyze module dependencies, which is exactly what the build tool does.

Comment: I'm curious as to the why you want modules not in a layer to be unavailable.  Is it to help identify what modules are required by the app but not in a layer?

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo I want to remove modules that are already in layer, leaving the others.